Strange duration value in a go program
I had a strange issue with a go program I developed. The program runs on a pocketbook ebook reader and calls an external program. I wanted to measure the time spent in the external program but got weird durations.
So I entered some debug output:
    startTime := time.Now()
    debug("StartTime: %s", startTime.Format("15:04:05"))
    // some external program called here
    endTime := time.Now()
    debug("EndTime: %s", endTime.Format("15:04:05"))
    duration := endTime.Sub(startTime)
    debug("Duration: %s", duration)

Debug showed this:
2024/08/07 18:23:07 StartTime: 18:23:07
2024/08/07 18:24:08 EndTime: 18:24:08
2024/08/07 18:24:08 Duration: 25.137969595s

I then switched to calculating the difference (as I needed just seconds anyway) to
    duration := endTime.Unix() - startTime.Unix()

Which gave me the expected results.
I'm wondering what could be wrong with my initial approach? Why is the calculated difference so far off?

It works on playground as expected: https://go.dev/play/p/lf-KIsMLJcq Btw, you have endTime in your first debug() call. Would this little repro run as expected on your device?

It also worked for me when running on the computer and not on the device (ARM7 processor with busybox linux). Thanks for spotting the Copy&Paste error.

startTime := time.Now()
fmt.Println("StartTime: %s", startTime.Format("15:04:05"))
// some external program called here
endTime := time.Now()
fmt.Println("EndTime: %s", endTime.Format("15:04:05"))
duration := endTime.Sub(startTime)
fmt.Println("Duration: %s", duration)

For me it is giving in microsecond.
StartTime: %s 13:42:15
EndTime: %s 13:42:15
Duration: %s 142.583µs

